# Computer continuously typing letter "p" and now won't turn on after shut down

Tags: windows-10, boot, malware, wireless-keyboard

I have a Gateway all-in-one desktop computer running Windows 10 with a Linksys wireless keyboard and mouse.  Last night the computer started typing the letter "p" continuously.

I tried multiple different variations of turning off the keyboard, mouse, unplugging the dongle, and restarting the PC.  Even when the keyboard was turned off and the wireless dongle was removed it continued to type "p".  At that point I disconnected from wifi.

I finally decided to shut down completely to let it sit for a few minutes and try again.  When I turn it on, an initial screen (can't remember exactly what now & I'm not home to look) comes up and then goes to black screen with the rotating wheel like it's working on starting windows.  But it just sits like that.  I tried multiple times, but that's all I get.

I'm not sure what to do at this point. Could it be a virus or malware? I'm not even sure if it gets far enough in boot up to try safe mode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately it's tough to get into safe mode at this point, especially with Windows 10, since F8 or Shift-F8 tend not to work on UEFI boot or with SSDs.

Comment: Disconnect that wireless KB and try a wired one, see if it boots.  See if the problem continues with a wired KB.